# How to fix "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" error?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, raspberry-pi3, amazon-echo

I'm trying to follow [this very basic tutorial](https://www.hackster.io/user00317224/control-raspberry-pi-gpio-using-amazon-echo-ngrok-de41d1) on how to get Alexa to turn on an LED attached to a Raspberry Pi, but I never get a successful launch of the skill. I always get a "There was a problem with the requested skill's response." I checked the Device Log and InvocationResponse is always null.

I followed all the steps in the tutorial, except for the part where I have to copy-paste the code on the Intent Schema box. I assume that part is already taken care of automatically in the latest Developer Console, correct? I checked the JSON Editor tab and most of the Intent Schema code given by the tutorial was already written. I tried editing the JSON Editor but that did not work -- the response error still shows up.

I looked at other forums and they said the python script that I'm running locally on the Pi may be the problem. The script is an exact copy of [this code](https://github.com/kanesurendra/RPizone/blob/master/echo-pi-ngrok/rpi-control.py) as suggested by the tutorial. Ngrok seems to be working as it gives a 200 OK on the terminal.

I really have no idea how I can start debugging this issue. Hopefully someone could help me! Thanks!

---

This is the python script that I'm running on the Pi:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, convert_errors
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import logging

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

app = Flask(__name__)
ask = Ask(app, '/')

logging.getLogger("flask_ask").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@ask.intent('GPIOControlIntent', mapping={'status': 'status'})
def gpio_status(status):

if status in ['on','high' ]:
  GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN)
  state = GPIO.input(21)
  if (state == True):
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(21,GPIO.HIGH)
    return statement('Lights are already on')
  else:
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(21,GPIO.HIGH)
    return statement('Turning lights {}'.format(status))

if status in ['off','low' ]:
  GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN)
  state = GPIO.input(21)
  print('status of light',state)
  if (state == False):
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)
    return statement('Lights are already off')
  else:
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)
    return statement('Turning lights {}'.format(status))

if __name__ == '__main__':
port = 5000 #the custom port you want
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

---

This is what is on the JSON Editor in the AWS Developer Console

```
{
"interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "raspberry pi",
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "GPIOControlIntent",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "status",
                        "type": "GPIO_Control"
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "turn the light {status}",
                    "turn {status} the light"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "types": [
            {
                "name": "GPIO_Control",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "value": "off"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "value": "on"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Add your code here, please.

Comment: I added the code in the main body! Thanks!